# CSS border-radius and -webkit-border-radius not working on iOS 5 UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, mobile-safari, css

I'm working on some CSS being used in a `UIWebView` in iOS. I'm able to round the corners of a div in iOS 6 using the `border-radius` property, but I can't replicate the effect in iOS 5.1 using either `border-radius` or `-webkit-border-radius` properties. Is there a workaround, or am I doing something wrong? Here's the CSS.

```
#ad-wrapper {
  postion:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-140px;
  margin-top:-109px;
  width:280px;
  height:218px;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius:12px;
  border-radius:12px;
}
```

which works for iOS 6:

[image: iOS 6 border radius works]

but not for iOS 5.1:

[image: iOS 5.1 border radius doesn't work]

I'm brand new to web development (having done mostly native iOS before this), so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS 5, I was able to fix it by applying `-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius`, `bottom-right-radius`, etc. to the correct sub elements.

I'd still like a better fix, as just using the single corner radius in one place is a much cleaner solution, but I may have to settle for this.